# Flutter: Changing Cards in Screen without rebuilding the whole page

Tags: flutter, dart, state

I am pretty new to Flutter / Dart and right now, I have a problem. I have a homepage in my App and it displays an AppBar, a BottomNavigationBar and a body. The body is a simple card with content in it. The problem is: I need to be able to display three different cards, depending on the status I get from a server.
So there is the ActiveCard, the InactiveCard and the ErrorCard. The ErrorCard has a Button to go back to the InactiveCard and the ActiveCard as well as the InactiveCard should be wrapped in an Inkwell or similar to start a ride for example.

Now I am wondering: I am not sure how to implement all this. Can I just create three Stateless Widgets for each Card and depending on the server status just "replace" or "change" the body in my homepage? And where can I "control" the current status? Like I said, the Cards need to be clickable and "erase" themselves to make space for the following card (e.g: InactiveTrip gets clicked, now there should be the Card for ActiveTrip, because I started my trip and the user should see that my trip is currently active)

I cant provide code really, because so far I have not really something with will be even close to the result I expect.
Maybe you have some tips and packages I can use.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert  the statelessWidget to statefulWidget ans use setState() method.This is
recommended for small application but if your apps have more complexity then you have learn the state Management like provider,bloc pattern or Mvvm architechture.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that, but I mean I have like three different Cards, means three widgets. An I am not sure if its possible to use setState to erase a current widget and replace it with another one...

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use statelessWidget for this purpose.
and you can use [bloc pattern](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc)

to manage the page state.

Answer (score 0):

I will use stateless for page and stream for the card content:

```
//Card model is your data modal
StreamController<Card> _streamController = StreamController();
Card _currentCard = /* default inactivate */;

StreamBuilder<bool>(
            stream: _streamController.stream,
            initialData: _currentCard,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Card> snapshot) {
              //return Container(/*content of your card*/);
            },
          ),

//Everytime you need to change the card content, you sink the new value
_streamController.sink.add(_currentCard = /*new card data modal*/);
```

Comment: Okay and what if my content is extremely different every time? Thank for the response though!